# simple question about the weak topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E $ a Hilbert space. Consider the ball $B_R (0) = \{ x \in E ;  || x|| \leq 1 \}$. We have $B_R (0)$ a Hilbert space. Let $ (U_i)$ the open sets of the weak topology of $E$. Consider the topology  $(E_i \cap B_R(0))$ for $B_R (0)$.  This topology for $B_R(0)$ is the weak topology of $B_R(0)$ . I believe that the answer is yes. But i dont know how to prove this. Someone can give me a help? If my affirmation is true then i understand the proof of a theorem..

Comment: $B_R(0)$ is not a Hilbert space. It's not even a vector space.

Comment: you're right . i will write better my question

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by David Mitra, $B_R(0)$ is not a vector space. Thus, it does not have a weak topology of its own; it can only get it from the ambient vector space, by restriction. Your description is accurate: we take all weakly open subsets of $E$ and intersect them with $B_R(0)$; this gives a topology on $B_R(0)$ (restriction topology or induced topology, as people call it). This is what one would call the weak topology on $B_R(0)$.

Examples of usage: (a) the weak topology on $B_R(0)$ is metrizable; (b) $B_R(0)$ is compact in the weak topology.

There is nothing to prove in your post; all that was stated there is a definition.